# use a field as a parameter for nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

I am curious if it is possible to use a fieldname as a parameter for express.

My sql statement is as follows:

```
const INSERT_VALUE_VIA_FIELD = "UPDATE businesses set ? = ? where userId = ?";
...


router.post("/update", async (req, res) => {
  const { field, value, userId } = req.body;
  connection.query(
    INSERT_VALUE_VIA_FIELD,
    [field, value, userId],
    async (error, rows) => {
      res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      if (error) {
        res.json({ error: error.sqlMessage });
        req.on("end", () => {
          res.statusCode = 400;
          res.end("Bad Request");
        });
      } else {
        res.json({ field, value, userId });
        req.on("end", () => {
          res.statusCode = 200;
          res.end("OK post");
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

I pass in the properties as follows:

```
{
    "field": "name",
    "value":"test",
    "userId": 23
}
```

in which i expect the mysql statement to run as:

```
"UPDATE businesses set name = "test" where userId = 23";
```

When i run this via postman, i get the following error:

```
"error": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('name') = 'test' where userId = 23' at line 1"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure understand you, but why do you not wrap your query with backtick(``), and then replace your column names? It is easy to use. However, you can try this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format

Answer (score 0):

So it isnt the most feasible answer, but it works. I have substituted the string with back ticks as suggested by Mostafa and passing in the `field` param within the statement as so:

```
router.post("/update", async (req, res) => {
  const { field, value, userId } = req.body;
  connection.query(
    `UPDATE businesses set ${field} = ? where userId = ?`,
    [value, userId],
    async (error, rows) => {
      res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      if (error) {
        res.json({ error: error.sqlMessage });
        req.on("end", () => {
          res.statusCode = 400;
          res.end("Bad Request");
        });
      } else {
        res.json({ field, value, userId });
        req.on("end", () => {
          res.statusCode = 200;
          res.end("OK post");
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```